# Export of MySQL database with --complete-insert does not include column names in resulting txt files

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export database with multiple tables into `csv` / `txt` files including column names. However, using `--complete-insert` flag in the statement does export `txt` files but without corresponding column headers. The exported `sql` file does contain the column headers.

This is the command I am using:

`mysqldump --password  --fields-optionally-enclosed-by='"' --fields-terminated-by=',' --tab /var/lib/mysql-files/ --complete-insert test`

I am using latest docker image with MySQL 8.0.28 installed on it. I tried different ways of including `--complete-insert` statement with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the following was easiest for me (some of the exports will be used within `python` based environment so keeping it all in one place was useful for me).

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import os

# Dummy connection settings values
pwd = "helloworld"
port = "3306"
database = "testapp"
container_name = "mysql-development"

# Connect to the database
mysql_conn_str = f"mysql+pymysql://root:{pwd}@{container_name}:{port}/{database}"
engine = create_engine(mysql_conn_str)
connection = engine.connect()

def save_files(x, engine, base_path = "./", **kwargs):

    save_path = os.path.join(base_path, f"{x}.csv")
    df = pd.read_sql_query(f"SELECT * FROM {x}", engine)

    df.to_csv(save_path, **kwargs)
    
# Execute queries
tables = pd.read_sql_query("SHOW TABLES;", engine)
tables[f"Tables_in_{database}"].apply(save_files, args=(engine, ), base_path = "/install", index = False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's how mysqldump works, by design. The option `--complete-insert` is irrelevant when using `--tab`.

When using `mysqldump --tab` the export is not formatted as INSERT statements. It's just a dump of CSV data, one file per table.

Then mysqldump executes `SELECT * INTO OUTFILE` for each table. The result of that SELECT statement is only the data, no header that includes column names.

The column names are implicit. They match the order of columns in the corresponding CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful! Is there a way for me to achieve what I want with `mysqldump` i.e. export of all tables in the database including the column headers?

Comment: Yes, don't use `--tab`.

Comment: Whoops sorry I tried that but receive `You must use option --tab with --fields-...`, I tried different permutations of the command to no effect for the moment.

Comment: The `--complete-insert` option only works if you are exporting data as an SQL file. The `--tab` and `--fields-*` options are for exporting data as a set of CSV files. You can't use these options together in mysqldump. If you want a tool that does exactly what you want, you have to code it yourself.

Comment: Ok that is helpful thank you very much, I will see if I can do that and then post it as an answer to the question. Thank you for such a quick reply and a clear explanation.